# rake cucumber: ok not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I just installed rspec and for some reason it broke cucumber

Here is the error file:

```
Morgans-MacBook-Pro:ticketee morganallen$ bundle exec cucumber
Using the default profile...
/Users/morganallen/test_folder/ticketee/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:58: unterminated string meets end of file (SyntaxError)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
```

**...**

[the repo](https://github.com/RubikCubes/ticketee)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[This line](https://github.com/RubikCubes/ticketee/blob/master/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb#L58) causes the problem, delete those two `end` statements surrounding the `"` and it will work.

Comment: yea, I just noticed that too!! Thanks for the answer!!